# Jquery scroll to offset target div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll to the div that is in the URL. It could be one of 21 IDs like:

url.com/test#lite1

url.com/test#lite2

url.com/test#lite3

I need this to happen on page load (user is coming from an ebook and should see the exact item they clicked on).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').load(function() {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -150
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

It doesn't work and I think it's because of this part (I have no idea what I'm doing here):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').load(function() {
```

I also want it to be in the center of the page (not at the top cut off like browsers do when scrolling to divs). Please let me know if this is correct:

```
$target.offset().top -150
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` contains the current hash in the URL so use that. As the hash is already in the URL(as you said that they come to page by clicking on link with hash) so you don't need to add it manually.
Try using this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top-150
      }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

Using wordpress, it seems the $ needs to be replaced by jQuery so it comes out to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top-150
      }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: http://www.tasteaholics.com/shopping-list-ingredients/#lite14

I'm trying it here but not working :/ Am I missing something or not loading something? i have jquery loaded for the page with: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @ramitaste In that page I see  `'scrollTop',` That comma after scrollTop  is causing syntax error use `:` instead of comma there. And also if you are using chrome then press `ctrl+shift+i` for developer tools and click on console tab it will show you syntax errors and other warnings in that page.

Comment: Ahh I switched back to your code (was trying Quantastical's code)  and replaced the $ with jQuery and it worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Interesting i found this @Zeus, thank you! But i want to include this function on a button click event > page load > scrollTo > ID/Class. Something currently i am trying which is not working on a WordPress environment.

`jQuery('.gform_next_button').click(function(){
    jQuery('html head').scrollTop( jQuery('.gform_wrapper').offset().top );  
    
});

jQuery('.gform_back_button').click(function(){
    jQuery('html head').scrollTop( jQuery('.gform_wrapper').offset().top );  
    
});`

Comment: @Aroganz If the page changes on button click then there is no point in putting scroll function in button click's callback. You need to put the scroll function in document ready callback which will run when the new page loads, and to detect where to scroll to you need to use hashes in URL. Throw in a `alert` function when testing to make sure that the callback is actually called.

Comment: @Zeus thanks for the heads-up, but the context in which i am intending to scroll is entirely different. Initially the user lands normally on top of the page. But when they scroll down and they are using a multi-step form, so when navigating 
 the form back and forth, the scrollTo Form anchor has to happen. Am missing on how to implement the piece of code on how to capture that when some one clicked one of those buttons on the form and upon page refresh scrollTo anchor action fired. [demo link](https://www.licensedagents.com.au/product/product-amarnath/)

Comment: @Aroganz I don't see the point of using scroll in on button click since the scroll has to be done when the page loads/refreshes, the only scenario where scrollTo is to be used inside button click function is when the application is SPA or loads the next form via AJAX. If the user uses your buttons to navigate through form then the hash will be present in the URL which should be enough to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try using the following jQuery plugins. I've used them on multiple projects. They're customizable and provide nice, smooth animation:

**scrollTo** ([download](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo), [documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.ca/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)) allows you to scroll to a specific element on the page. Basic usage: `$(element).scrollTo(target);`

**localScroll** ([download](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll), [documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.ca/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html)) requires scrollTo as a dependency, and handles anchors for you. You can apply it to specific set of links by selecting their container: `$('#link-container').localScroll();`, or you can activate it globally: `$.localScroll();`